# looping regex in directory and saving output

Tags: python

I was able to run the regex on multiple files, I want to save the output of this like `name_of_file_clean.txt`.

Trying to find the best way.

```
import os, re
import glob

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=CN=)(.*?)(?=,)')
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(file) as fp:
        for result in pattern.findall(fp.read()):
           print(result)
```

Comment: You want `pattern.sub()` to do the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll just open the output file and use the `print` functions `file` keyword argument to write to the file

```
import os, re
import glob

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=CN=)(.*?)(?=,)')
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(file) as fp:
        with open(file[:-4] + '_clean.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            for result in pattern.findall(fp.read()):
               print(result, file=outfile)
```